# Como setar o click na ListView

Tags: android, android-studio

Bom criei uma tela de pesquisa com Pain text e adicionei uma ListView para mostrar as sugestões, porem como faço para setar o click do item que aparece na lista?

Codigo java

```
public class Tempo_Real extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText edtlinha,edtparada;
    Button btmbuscar;
    String linhas [] = {"Alvorada","Maracana","Res.Salvação"};
    private ListView lista;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tempo__real);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Lista);
        edtlinha = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtLinha);
        edtparada = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtParada);
        btmbuscar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBuscar);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, linhas);
        lista.setAdapter(adapter);
        edtlinha.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(s);

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

        lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                    long id) {
                // Faz o que você quiser. Com o parâmetro "position” você pode obter o item correspondente do Adapter de acordo com o item clicado.
            }
        });

    }
    public void btnBuscar (View view) {
        String stlinha = edtlinha.getText().toString();
        String stparada = edtparada.getText().toString();


        if(stlinha.equals("Alvorada")&& stparada.equals("CA1507")) {
            Intent intencao = new Intent(this,Alvorada_Tempo_Real.class);
            startActivity(intencao);

        }

        if(stlinha.equals("Maracana")&& stparada.equals("CE1507")) {
            Intent intencao = new Intent(this,Maracana_Tempo_Real.class);
            startActivity(intencao);

        }
        if(stlinha.equals("Res.Salvação")&& stparada.equals("CE1507")) {
            Intent intencao = new Intent(this,Res_Salvacao_Tempo_Real.class);
            startActivity(intencao);

        }


        else if(stlinha.equals("")|| stparada.equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"linha ou Parada não Cadastrada",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        else {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"linha ou Parada não Cadastrada",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ListView listView;
...
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // Faz o que você quiser. Com o parâmetro "position” você pode obter o item correspondente do Adapter de acordo com o item clicado.
        }
    });
```

Comment: Ola Márcio fiz o método mais ao abrir a aplicação ele fecha com erro "A aplicação parou"

Comment: O meu código está genérico. Você adaptou para o nome do objeto que você já estava usando? Posta o seu código atualizado e qual o erro exato que deu.

Comment: Então vó colocar código sem alteração ai você me mostra onde posso modificar ok?

Comment: Editei a Pergunta com o Código atualizado, lembrado que eu não fiz uma classe adaptadora para a ListView

Comment: O código da listview parece correto, tente postar o erro que aparece na janela de Run do Android Studio. Lá informa qual o erro que deu e em qual linha do código. Só olhando o código por aqui não ajuda muito. Eu recomendo que você dê uma olhada nesses 2 cursos. Eu fiz e aprendi muito: https://br.udacity.com/course/android-development-for-beginners--ud837/ e https://br.udacity.com/course/android-basics-multi-screen-apps--ud839/

Comment: Ok o erro na hora de executar o app no meu caso uso meu celular, ao clicar no botão que me leva a tela de pesquisa da o seguinte erro "projeto bus parou de funcionar". Quando eu retiro o código setOnItemClickListener abre normal

Comment: Bom depois de reiniciar o PC resolvi fazer o teste e o app rodou normal porém quando clico no item não acontece nada

Comment: Não acontece nada porque o método que postei só tem a casca, rs. Você tem que implementar algo dentro do método para que aconteça algo. Cara, sugiro que você realmente dê uma olhada nos cursos que postei acima. Eu tentei começar a desenvolver Android por tentativa e erro e só estava perdendo tempo e não saía nada, pois são muitos conceitos novos, mesmo pra mim que já programava para PC. Esses cursos estão muito didáticos, pois parte do princípio que você nunca programou em nada. Aprendi bastante.

Comment: Ha sim como disse sou iniciante, porem, não vó te muito tempo porque preciso apresentar segunda feira na minha aula mais valeu

Answer (score 0):

eu dei uma olhada no seu codigo e reparei em um método existente que deveria fazer essa função.

No seu código tem esse método que serve para capturar os evento de Click:

```
lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                    long id) {
                // Faz o que você quiser. Com o parâmetro "position” você pode obter o item correspondente do Adapter de acordo com o item clicado.
            }
        });
```

esse método não está funcionando ou você quer outra alternativa para ele?

Answer (score -1):

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            //aqui vc irá fazer a acao com o click pegando uma posicao da sua lista, coloquei um exemplo de iniciar uma nova tela passando o item clicado por parametro.
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MinhaProximaTela.class);
            intent.putExtra("mParametro", mParametro[position]);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```